# Ionic PUSH with iOS - Attempting to badge the application icon but haven't received permission from the user to badge the application

Tags: ios, xcode, push-notification, ionic-framework

I've install PushPlugin for Ionic and I've follow the tutorial for implementing this in device iOS (Until I have the new provisioning profile).
I've define the new profile in xCode, but when I try to start my App, I have this message :

> "Attempting to badge the application icon but haven't received permission from the user to badge the application".

I can send and receive alerts via ionic.io Dashboard, but I don't have the request from my device for Allow or not the push notification.
I want to display a native notification.

I've already sent the p12 certificat with command

> iOS Dev Push Certificate File (.p12) ~/Desktop/CertificatsPush.p12 
> Successfully uploaded certificate

And activate the developpement mode

> ionic push --production-mode=n
>   
> Successfully set development mode

And this is my App.JS :

```
myApp.run(function($ionicPlatform, $rootScope, $state, UserService, position) {

  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    var user = UserService.getUser()

    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleBlackTranslucent();
    }

    var push = new Ionic.Push({
    "debug": true
    });

    push.register(function(token) {
    console.log("Device token:",token.token);
    });

    if (UserService.userIsLoggedIn()) {
      $state.go('tabprofil')
    } else {
      facebookConnectPlugin.getLoginStatus(function(success) {
        if (success.status === 'connected') 
          $state.go('tabprofil')
        else
          $state.go('signin')
      })
    }

  })
```

I can add code if you want, please, save my day !
Thanks all folks for reading and helping ! ;)